# How to make Visual Studio format dictionary initialization?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0, autoformatting

All Visual Studios (2012 too) do not format the following:

```
_messageProcessor = new Dictionary<ServerDataTypes, MessageProcessor>()
{
    {ServerDataTypes.FrameData,       ProcessFrameData  }   ,
    {    ServerDataTypes.ServerStatusResult,ProcessServerStatusResult     },
    {   ServerDataTypes.PlayerMessage,    ProcessPlayerMessage},
    ....
};
```

How can I make my Visual Studio 2010 (or 2012) to auto-format that? I need the following result:

```
_messageProcessor = new Dictionary<ServerDataTypes, MessageProcessor>()
{
    { ServerDataTypes.FrameData, ProcessFrameData },
    { ServerDataTypes.ServerStatusResult, ProcessServerStatusResult },
    { ServerDataTypes.PlayerMessage, ProcessPlayerMessage },
     ...
};
```

It's like in the auto-properties for the newly created objects. The format is working for that. But not for this. So, how to fix it?

Comment: resharper's "code cleanup" will do something very similar to this. Is that an option?

Comment: When I removes last ; with backspace an then types ; it does what you want. But as I can undersrand you want to work it with Format Document command. Is it true?

Comment: @er-v retyping the semicolon **is** the `format line` tool; the `format document `formats all lines but both these options do not format the above text.

Comment: Oh, It's becouse I have a resharper. Clean VS realy does not do it.

Comment: Up to vs2013 the problem still exists also for arrays and lists initializers

Comment: VS2022 still exists

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer: you can't with VS out of the box. Resharper comes close, but it's reformatting doesn't quite do this style either. I've actually submitted a request for it do do this.

You might look for some other extension or perhaps develop a macro of some sort.

Comment: This is true for all collection initializers (at least without Resharper).  :( If you are curious about current issue thread: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/779

Comment: Upvoted not because I'm happy with the answer, but at least I can stop trying to get it to work.