# How can I make Visual Studio 2022 format wrapped lines?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, indentation

In principle, the Visual Studio 2022 formatter does indent lines. However, it indents wrapped lines incorrectly.

If I use this example

```cs
class C
 { // incorrect
  string P1 => // incorrect
  "foo" // incorrect
   + "bar"; // incorrect

    string P2
    {
     get // incorrect
     { // incorrect
     string s = "foo" // incorrect
      .Trim() // incorrect
       .Trim(); // incorrect
         return s; // incorrect
        }
    }
}
```

the formatter will produce this:

```cs
class C
{ // fixed
    string P1 => // fixed
    "foo" // still incorrect
     + "bar"; // still incorrect

    string P2
    {
        get // fixed
        { // fixed
            string s = "foo" // fixed
             .Trim() // still incorrect
              .Trim(); // still incorrect
            return s; // fixed
        }
    }
}
```

There are not even any warnings from the many [code analysis code-style rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/) that are configured in my `.editorconfig`.

Such as a mess as in my example may not appear often in practice, because while editing, the editor somehow does understand how to indent wrapped lines correctly:

```cs
class C
{
    string P1 => "foo"_<-Type enter here, then...
        _<- cursor will be here.
```

But it will still happen in practice when editing code.

Can this be fixed, is it a known bug or a new bug?

There are related questions, but they either [involve ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013876/) or are [too old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324453/).

Comment: My won similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879503/how-to-make-visual-studio-format-dictionary-initialization

Comment: In short: VS still can't format ALL code correctly. :)

Comment: Wow, this is embarrassing for Microsoft. 

Comment: Regarding this issue, you can go to [Visual Studio Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) to give feedback. Our team will also pay attention to the progress of this issue.